# Why is my code not sorting values correctly

Tags: python, sorting

```
numbers = (input("Please enter your numbers: ")).split(' ')

print (numbers)
list(map(int, numbers))
numbers.sort()

print (numbers)
```

I am trying to get my code to sort the users input from smallest to biggest with negatives too, but I cant seem to get it to work. I am fairly new to coding so detailed explanations would be really helpful.

Comment: `list(map(int, numbers))` <- this line is leaving `numbers` in its original state.  Reassign the value to numbers like this:  `numbers = list(map(int, numbers))` and you should have better luck.

Comment: thanks guys i got it no need for future comments :)

Comment: @nicomp Disagree.

Comment: @Chowlett2 Would you agree that the statement
list(map(int, numbers))
has no effect?

Comment: @nicomp yes, because you haven't assigned any variables, nor have you printed the result of that statement.